# How do I control a switch via WiFi?

Tags: networking, wifi, microcontroller

I want to build an android app that controls an appliance.

I did some online research and found out that I'll be needing a WiFi module (for example ESP32).

My question is, how do I integrate control of said module into my python\ Java code, and can I use my pc as the server with which it interacts?

Since interacting with a something physical via code is new to me, any other tips are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with a microcontroller like ESP32 is very different from developing Android apps with Java or Python. If this is new to you, I recommend to have a look at [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/), start working on a smaller project and perhaps read [Making Embedded Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449302149).

Both Bluetooth and WiFi sounds like viable alternatives to your problem. Your Java or Python app on Android or a PC will be a separate app and interact with the appliance over Bluetooth or Wifi. The appliance like ESP32 is a microcontroller that likely will be implemented in C, C++ or Rust although micropython might be an alternative.